# Is there a formula for the product of two zeta functions?

Tags: soft-question, zeta-functions

Is there a formula/theorem for the product of multiople zeta functions? For example let's say I need to compute $\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$, what should I do? I would be very thankful if someone could help me out.

Comment: $\zeta(2n)\cdot \zeta(2m), \: n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ certainly has a closed form. But with $\zeta(2n+1)$ I believe there is no nice closed form.

Comment: When I read "product of two zeta-functions", I assumed you have two different zeta-functions or $L$-functions which you want to multiply. But your question is about multiplying different *values* of the *one (Riemann) zeta function*. Maybe you can express that more clearly in the title.

Comment: In my experience, The product of two zeta function is that. However the product of two summation equal to the zeta function given that they are connected in upper limit before the are regularized, there's an additional rule, mainly that before you do any manipulation the "shape" needs to be preserved. Easiest way to solve it, is taking the undefined sum, and then take the delta, and then regularized sum.  occures most often if you have 1 function and write it as two regularized sums you should write it so that's clear they are connected in regularization.